# Mostrar registros de Base de datos en tabla

Tags: python

No consigo definir de forma correcta éste método para mostrar registros de una base de datos en una tabla de una aplicación, los datos de mi base de datos;

```
def get_exp(self):
        exp = self.tree.get_children()
        #Recorrer:
        for element in exp:
            self.tree.delete(element)
        #Consulta de datos:
        query = 'SELECT * FROM tablaExp ORDER BY num DESC'
        dbRows = self.run_query (query)
        #Rellenar los datos:
        for row in dbRows:
            self.tree.insert('', 0, text = row[0][1][2][3][4])
```

Se trata de 5 columnas (ejemplo: a, b, c, d y e) con datos text, y quiero mostrarlos en las cinco columnas de mi aplicación, cada uno en su sitio, y sé que el problema lo tengo en esta última línea (text = row[0][1][2][3][4]), he probado de mil maneras a trasladar los cinco datos, ¿Podríais confirmarme si esta es la forma correcta de escribir la línea?

El error que me sale al ejecutar es:

`"int" object is not subscriptable.`

Muchas gracias!

Con la propuesta de @rubialesalberto consigo eliminar el error, pero sigo sin conseguir mostrar los registros de la base de datos en la tabla de mi aplicación, si pruebo con un print (row), salen perfectamente los registros de la base de datos en filas (la primera columna es un id, pero que no quiero mostrar en la tabla):

(11, 'fasasf', 'gdsh', 'twert', 'dsgsdf', 'bvvb')

(4, 'asfasf', 'fasf', 'afgd', 'hgdhs', None)

(6, 'asfa', 'safasdf', 'fasgggfh', 'fghfdgh', 'jjfkg')

(7, 'asf', 'tyut', 'oioyup', 'i', '')

Son ejemplos... ¿se os ocurre algún error que pueda estar cometiendo?¿Puede ser que esté confunidiéndome con los índices y el id? Porque en mi tabla mi intención es no mostrar el id...

Comment: Creo que el error viene porque no hay datos en alguno de las row... por lo que cuando intentas hacer row[indice] devuelve el error. Intenta hacer un print(row) para ver el contenido de cada query.

Comment: si row es una fila.. yo dudo muchisimo que puedas hacer row[0][1] etc... o sea.. que estas buscando devolver? el valor de cada columna concatenado? en donde leiste que podias hacer algo asi?

Answer (score 1):

El error `"int" object is not subscriptable.` te está diciendo que estás intentado acceder mediante indice a un `int` lo cual no es posible, porque solo se puede acceder mediante indices a ciertas colecciones (por ejemplo: tuplas, listas, arrays, etc.). Para se más claro, te pongo un ejemplo gráfico de lo que está intentando hacer tu programa:

```
print(5[2])
```

Esto te da el error antes mencionado, ya que no puedes acceder a nada, dentro del número *5*.

El error probablemente te viene de aquí, en donde indicas que quieres acceder a un elemento, que se encuentra dentro de 5 colecciones:

```
self.tree.insert('', 0, text = row[0][1][2][3][4])
```

La solución a tu problema puede ser cambiar esa linea:

```
self.tree.insert('', 0, text = str(row[0]) + str(row[1]) + str(row[2]) + str(row[3]) + str(row[4]))
```

Si ya tienes formato *string* la función `str()` no te sería necesaria, pero lo he puesto por seguridad.